Async method vs. property C#
I need an advice to right approach to this issue.
Let's say I have class which have multiple properties, multiple of them are another classes. To get these classes I need to make operations which takes time like select from database. And also I need to force reload them.
This is example of code:
private EntArchElement? classifier;

//approach 1
public EntArchElement Classifier
{
    get
    {
        if (classifier is not null) return classifier;

        classifier = Repository.GetElementAsync(ClassifierGuid).Result;
        return classifier;
    }
}

//approach 2
public async Task<EntArchElement> GetClassifierAsync(bool force = false)
{
    if (!force && classifier is not null) return classifier;

    classifier = await Repository.GetElementAsync(ClassifierGuid);
    return classifier;
}

I am showing to you two approaches which I have in a mind. But first approach, it calls DbContext method with .Result. I don't like this approach because it blocks the thread.
Second approach I like, but I have an issue with that, I will have a lot of methods in the class. If I will need set too and I will need multiple different classes.
I also tried Lazy, but I didn't know proper way to force reload.
Do you know a pattern how to deal with it? Or do you know better solution? Can you share it?

There's no comparison. The method is asynchronous, the property blocks and can actually result in deadlocks. What you posted contains no EF code anyway. The whole point of ORMs like EF is to load actual graphs of objects, giving the impression of working with an object database. If you want to lazily load related data that's not always needed, use Lazy loading. And if your "repository" doesn't work that way ... that's why putting a low-level repository over a high level ORM is an antipattern

If you want to abstract EF or any ORM, you need a higher level abstraction than the multi-entity Unit-of-Work, ie DbContext. DbContext isn't a connection to abstract. A real Repository in this case would load and return all the objects needed by a specific use case instead of loading them one by one. After the application modifies all the objects it needs, the UoW/DbContext will automatically detect and persist all changes to all the entities it tracks.

If we're to assume a UI thread (is involved), one or more observable collections are implied to handle the async UI startup gracefully. Unless there's another reason, it's about "looking" performant (first) that matters.

I would generally expect properties to be cheap to access. A blocking database call is in most context not cheap. Using .Result will also block the call, and may increase the risk of a deadlock if used in a UI application.
Caching the result might avoid some problematic use cases, like repeated access, but may introduce new issues. If the value can change you need some cache invalidation mechanism, and that is another thing the user of your class needs to be aware of, and will make your class more difficult to use correctly.
The method variant is much clearer. Since it is a method it tells me that it is probably doing more than just returning a field. Being named *Async and returning a task is also a strong hint that it involves some kind of IO. It also provides an built in way to invalidate the cache, but I might consider replacing the bool with a non optional enum: GetClassifierAsync(CachePolicy.Reuse) is likely easier to read and understand than GetClassifierAsync().
